# Vertically centering two <div class="span6">'s within Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**EDIT**: Just wanted to clarify that these spans have unknown height (because of responsiveness)!

I'm trying to vertically align two `<div class="span6">`'s within a `<div class="row">` in Bootstrap and I'm having problems using any of my usual tricks, such as `display: inline-block;` or `display: table-cell;` (here's the JSFiddle I was working on: http://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/).

Here's what I was trying to use, which does not work in Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="display: table">
        <div class="span6" style="height: 300px; background: red; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle;">
            Block 1 - Vertically center me please!
        </div>
        <div class="span6" style="height: 170px; background: blue; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle;">
            Block 2- Center me too
        </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

Is it possible to vertically align these two `.span6`'s such that both the height of `Block1` and `Block2` are unknown? I'd like to use Bootstrap because of the responsible features, but for tablet+ we'd like the content to vertically align.

Comment: Have you considered FlexBox? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think you're making very clear if you want the **content of the `div`'s** to be vertically centered or **the actual `div`'s themselves**. Anyway, there's a solution to both options:

#### Vertically centering the actual `div`'s

First a solution which vertically aligns the `div`'s: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VwgwE/3/)</kbd>

It works by setting `display: table;` on `.container` and `display: table-cell;` on `.row`. Once that is done you can set `vertical-align: middle;` on `.row` to vertically center its content.

I have also had to manually force the width of `.row` to be `960px`, this is not very responsive (you could fix that using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)), but the `margin-left` of `-20px` which Bootstrap sets on `.row` doesn't work after setting `display: table-cell;` on `.row`. Not forcibly adding these extra `20px` would result in the second `div` ending up below the first because they won't both fit together on the same line anymore. I have set some `height: 100%;`'s on all elements for demonstration purposes.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    min-width: 960px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

#### Vertically centering the `div`'s contents

If you wanted to vertically center the content of the `div`'s, you can do that by setting `display: table;` on `.row` and setting `display: table-cell;` on `.span6`. You'd also need to get rid of `float: left;` on `.span6` by setting it to `float: none`.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this option: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VwgwE/2/)</kbd>

Comment: So I got this working with a few adjustments - I had to set margin-left; 0 on the row and then for then set padding-right: 20px for all container .span*'s, and .span*:last-child { padding-right: 0px } to make up for lack of margin (which is not supported by table cell).

All in all a working solution, thank you

Comment: @Walker I actually have the same problem but can't make it work. I have 4 span3 in a row-fluid. and each span3 has images of variable height and hence I want to vertically align images. I knew that table-cell trick would work but somehow not clicking for me. here is my css modifications, please help if u get some clue. .row-fluid {
display: table;
}
.span3 {
  text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a fixed height and only a single line you can easily use `line-height` for this.

```
.span6:first-child{
    line-height:300px;
}

.span6{
    line-height:170px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/1/

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear: the height of these two blocks are unknown, so I don't think we can use line-height.

Comment: In that case you can't no, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

try doing this http://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="display: table">
        <div class="span6" style="height: 300px; background: red; display: table-cell !important; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -150px; ">
            Block 1 - Vertically center me please!
        </div>
        <div class="span6 offset6" style="height: 170px; background: blue; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle; top: 50%; margin-top: -85px ;  position: absolute " >Block 2- Center me too
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear: the height of these two blocks are unknown, so I don't think we can use line-height

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

So I was wrong, my original answer doesn't work and here's why. Bootstrap is still applying a `float: left` to all `<div class="span*">` elements.

```
/* From Bootstrap; some differences based on media query */
[class*="span"]
{
   float: left;
   min-height: 1px;
   margin-left: 30px;
}
```

You can override these rules by making the following change to the `.cell` style from my original answer:

```
.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, you'll then lose the responsive "stacking" of the elements on small screens (which I don't think you want) and instead retain the "table" appearance. To prevent this from happening, you will most likely have to make the `display: table; float: none;` style conditional with your own media queries.

Even still, the intent of Bootstrap was not to display content as a CSS table so by overriding styles to do so, you risk introducing other "bugs" into your display.

Here's an updated fiddle to review: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y8Jv/3/

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y8Jv/1/?

My markup and styles don't look much different than yours, but I'm getting the vertical centering you're asking for.

**Markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row table">
        <div class="span6 cell">What Is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
        <div class="span6 cell">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table
{
    display: table;
}

.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two rows with each row taking half of the screen.

Why not use the `offset3` to shift over your row a quarter of the way (thus putting it where you want it), and then still use `span6` in two separate rows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset3 span6">Block 1 - Vertically center me please!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset3 span6">Block 2- Center me too</div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use some tricks with jquery...

1) get the span height with id

2) do some math for margin top

3) then, set css

It also works on window resize.

DEMO on jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/q49Da/

## HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">   
        <div id="red" class="span6" style="background: red;width:40%;float:left;margin-right:5%;">
            Block 1 - Vertically center me please!<br />
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
        </div>
        <div id="blue" class="span6" style="background: blue;width:40%;float:left;">
            Block 2- Center me too<br />
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ver_top = ($(window).height() - $('#red').height()) / 2;
    $('#red').css( "margin-top", ver_top+'px' );

    var ver_top2 = ($(window).height() - $('#blue').height()) / 2;
    $('#blue').css( "margin-top", ver_top2+'px' );

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var ver_top = ($(window).height() - $('#red').height()) / 2;
        $('#red').css( "margin-top", ver_top+'px' );

        var ver_top2 = ($(window).height() - $('#blue').height()) / 2;
        $('#blue').css( "margin-top", ver_top2+'px' );
    });
});
```