# Vertically align images in bootstrap span classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to vertically align images in a twitter bootstrap used css.
I have a fluid row and 4 span classes `span3` within that row. I have used table and table-cell trick but it does not work for me.

here is the sample code.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
                 <img src="http://bumblesea.com/blog/indie-fashion-design/lou-o-bedlam-flickr-fashion-photographer-300x300.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
                 <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ku9h6qcBRn1qat5v7o1_500.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
                 <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_KWR_gvxCigs/Ss0lQXRQj7I/AAAAAAAADkg/drrHCuZd8mA/s400/fashion1965-6.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
                 <img src="http://www.urbalicious.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/givenchy_jakandjil.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>
```

and the CSS that i have modified is

```
.row-fluid {
display: table-cell;
}
.span3 {
  text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}
```

However it works if I use a `span12` class and put 4 div inside the span12 using `display:table-cell` but it breaks the responsive nature so cannot afford this.

I guess here [Vertically centering two <div class="span6">'s within Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682346/vertically-centering-two-div-class-span6s-within-bootstrap) is the similar problem but suggestions does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use !important to overwrite bootstrap rules, or use heavier selector:
http://jsfiddle.net/HGy7a/

```
.row-fluid {
    display: table!important;
    float:none!important;
}
.span3 {
    float: none!important;
    display: table-cell!important;
    vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

Comment: I am loosing the responsiveness here, result is same that I got using 4 div inside a class span12 div, instead of span3 coming one below each other in small screen, it comes in a single row. also the margin between images is gone coz of float:none may be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u27qp/ its a matter of selector i guess. You need to be explicite in your css stylesheet, to get dow right to this container and avoid other. You may then , have no need of !important.